# Distinguishing Records with Related Fields

Tags: database-design, ms-access, ms-access-2010

*I'm a newer user (obviously) and would greatly appreciate question writing suggestions as well as answer suggestions:*

I have a lot of interrelated tables which largely depend on my `Products` table, which is the master list of a certain product. Much of the information for any given product is determined by traits from the `Shipments` table. There is a `one-to-many` relationship between `Shipments` and `Products`. Each shipment has a `Product Version` field, but in addition to having a unique version, any shipment may be a trial shipment.

### Which is the better design?

There are two workable designs which come to mind.

#### 1. Current Design

The `Product Version` field contains values for each possibility. For example, a product of version 7.6 would have the value `7.6`, but a 7.6 product which is a trial would be `7.61`. To select all 7.6 products, I would use a `Like "7.6*"` statement. This keeps all of the versions in one table and I have this documented for the next user. The irritating thing is that I have to have a field containing the necessary SQL to query that specific version. This SQL is located in a `ProductVersion` table.

#### 2. Adding a Field

I could have a True/False field for each shipment which indicated if it was a trial... (I also have to take into account the ease with which new users will be able to use this without me, but as that's a bit subjective, that's not the core question.)

### I don't know if this makes a difference but

Part of the fun with my current setup is that only some records in `Products` have associated `Shipments`, since for sometime the shipments were not recorded. The shipments are also imported into the database in a different process, sometimes after the associated product.

So:
**Is it a better design to add a boolean field for trial products?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I encourage those more knowledgeable than I to edit this answer or question with additional information if it would be beneficial to those reading this in the future.*

After experimentation, I've implemented **Option 2**, the boolean field for trial version.

I think this solution is

- better normalized and
- more clear to users

when each attribute is broken down into its own field (rather than having a version field which has to describe multiple attributes like product version and whether or not it is trial).

In some way it could be beneficial if I could just *add new version numbers* like 7.622 then 7.6221 to get more specific, but this can be confusing to decipher and is also somewhat **arbitrary**. The alternative--breaking the version/trial into multiple fields--also discourages others from creating new potentially duplicate or unnecessary version numbers which make things harder to find/query.

These additional fields, such as the trial boolean, are related to each `Product` through the **one-to-many** relationship between `Products` and `Shipments`.